# C++ Program for Half-Life Determination using functions and file input

Tags: c++, function, file, visual-c++, std

Here is the problem I am working on:

> You are to develop a menu-driven program that will allow the analyses of data from the file `Patient_Data.txt` using the following equations:

[image]

> > Ct = C0e^-kt
> >
> > t1/2  = ln(2)/k
>
> where:
>   **Ct** is the concentration in ug/L at time t
>   **C0** is the initial concentration in ug/L
>   **t** is the time in hrs
>   **k** is the time constant (1/hrs)
>   **t1/2** is the half-life in hrs
>
> - The user of the program must be able to obtain the average half-life (to 2 decimal places) along with the number of measurements used to calculate the average for any of the 5 patients for which data has been collected.
> - The program must also be able to display the 2 patient numbers and averages of the patients that have the highest half-life average values.
> - A menu must be used to select the different options with an additional option for Exit. The program must run until exit is selected by the user.
> - The program must be designed using functions.
>
>   - A function called `analyzeData` must take as input the patient number and must return both the average half-life and the number of measurements in the average for the input patient number.
>   - A separate function called `halfLife` is to be used for calculating the t1/2 (half-life) based on C0 (initial concentration), Ct (concentration at time t) and t (time) that are in the data file.
>   - A third function called `highest2halfLifes` must also be used to determine the two patients with the longest average half-life from the five different patients. All four values (`patient1`, `halfLife1`, `patient2`, `halfLife2`) must be returned to the main function.

The following data file `Patient_Data.txt` lists values for C0, Ct, and t, respectively

```
1 325 160 2.0
1 600 100 6.2
2 325 220 1.0
3 600 200 4.4
4 325 100 3.0
4 325 88 3.2
2 600 200 3.3
2 325 100 3.3
4 600 210 3.4
5 325 105 3.5
1 600 110 6.0
3 325 100 3.1
2 600 120 5.5
2 600 125 5.5
5 120 60 2.2
2 325 100 3.4
```

---

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool analyzeData(int patientNum, double *avgHalfLife, int *numMeasurements);
double halfLife(double C0, double Ct, double t);
bool highest2halfLifes(double avgHalfLife, int *patient1, double *halflife1, int *patient2, double *halflife2);


int main()
{
    int patientNum;
    char option;
    double avgHalfLife = 0;
    int numMeasurements = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "\nNew Pain Drug - Half-Life Determination\n";
        cout << "---------------------------------------\n";
        cout << " [P] - Patient Summary\n";
        cout << " [H] - Highest two half-lifes\n";
        cout << " [X] - to Exit\n";
        cout << "\nEnter Option: ";
        cin >> option;

        switch (option)
        {
        case 'p': 
            cout << "Enter patient number (1-5): ";
            cin >> patientNum;
            analyzeData(patientNum, &avgHalfLife, &numMeasurements);
            cout << "Half-life of patient #" << patientNum << " is " << fixed << setprecision(2) << avgHalfLife << " hrs, using " << numMeasurements << " measurements.\n";
            break;

        case 'h': 
            break;

        case 'x': option = false;
            break;

        default: cout << "Invalid option entered.\n";
        }
    }
    while (option);
    return 0;
}

bool analyzeData(int patientNum, double *avgHalfLife, int *numMeasurements)
{
    double C0, Ct, t, t1/2;
    double sumHalfLifes = 0;

    int patient;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open ("Patient_Data.txt");

if (fin)
{
    while (fin >> patient >> C0 >> Ct >> t) 
    {
        if (patient == patientNum)
        {
            bool analyzeData = true;
            t½ = halfLife(C0, Ct, t);

            *numMeasurements++;
            sumHalfLifes = sumHalfLifes + t½;
            *avgHalfLife = sumHalfLifes/ *numMeasurements;
        }
    }
}
else
cout << "Error opening file.";

    fin.close();
    return analyzeData;
}


double halfLife(double C0, double Ct, double t)
{
    double k, t1/2;

    k = - log(Ct/C0)/t;
    t½ = log(2)/k;

    return t1/2;
}

bool highest2halfLifes(double avgHalfLife, int *patient1, double *halflife1, int *patient2, double *halflife2)
{
    double highest = avgHalfLife;

    if (avgHalfLife > highest)
        highest = avgHalfLife;

    return highest2halfLifes;
}
```

Here is the output I get:

[image]

What I need help with is getting the function `analyzeData` to return the correct data because as of now, the program output is always zero. Also, we haven't learned anything about `std::` yet so I'd prefer not to use it. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue or corrections to my code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _`sumHalfLifes = sumHalfLifes + t½;`_ Huh?? Please don't use such characters (`½`) for variable names. That can make your code completely unreadable for others. Better stick to something like `t_1_2` or similar.

Comment: Also provide the complete input and output you get ([MCVE]), otherwise it's unlikely someone can help you with your problem.

Comment: How the hell did you get `t½` in your code to compile?

Comment: @QuestionC There are compilers that allow to do this.

Comment: Removed the [tag:c] tag. That is clearly c++ code.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit my question is how do you get the values from the `analyzeData` function to be assigned to the variables in `main`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for your input. I've edited the question, do you know how I can solve this??

Comment: @lockeal Well, you don't test if the `fin.open ("Patient_Data.txt");` worked. If not the `while()` loop won't be entered at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ okay, I added an if statement to test the file and the output is the same so I think the file opens alright

Comment: In Your code all the t1/2 are actually dividing a variable t1 by 2

Comment: @lockeal: If THAT is really your question -- how to get values from a function assigned to variables in `main` -- don't you think your question is a bit on the long side for that? An example for that could be whipped up in <10 lines, with no reference to half life or funny variable names at all...

Comment: @Bob__ Nope, see the other comments regarding that. `½` is treated as a single character.

Comment: @DevSolar well that's one of my questions. Basically I'm stuck and have no idea where to go from here. I just though I should include the rest of my program in case I made a mistake somewhere else

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ In the function halfLife() he declares `double k, t1/2;` and then `return t1/2;` or at least so I see

Comment: @Bob__ Ouch, seems that the OP was changing this meanwhile wrongly, not noticing that `/` can't be used in a variable name. Well I gave some advice how to name that variable correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things incorrect with your code. I'll explain each as I get to them:

> ```
> bool analyzeData(int patientNum, double *avgHalfLife, int *numMeasurements);
> //...
> bool highest2halfLifes(double avgHalfLife, int *patient1, double *halflife1, int *patient2, double *halflife2);
> ```

It is simpler and easier to read when using pass-by-reference instead of passing a pointer by-value in order to return multiple values:

```
bool analyzeData(int patientNum, double& avgHalfLife, int& numMeasurements);
//...
bool highest2halfLifes(double avgHalfLife, int& patient1, double& halflife1, int& patient2, double& halflife2);
```

> ```
> int patientNum;
> char option;
> double avgHalfLife = 0;
> int numMeasurements = 0;
> ```

Be consistent in your code.
Always initialize variables and with the correct datatype value.

```
int patientNum = 0;
char option = 0;
double avgHalfLife = 0.0;
int numMeasurements = 0;
```

> ```
>        switch(option) {
>        //...
>                analyzeData(patientNum, &avgHalfLife, &numMeasurements);
>        //...
> ```

Since we are now passing values by reference we do not pass the address:

```
switch(option) {
//...
analyzeData(patientNum, avgHalfLife, numMeasurements);
//...
```

> ```
>            case 'x': option = false;
>                break;
> ```

Be consistent in whitespace and formatting.
A `char` is not a `bool` but any non-zero value is treated as true and any zero value is treated as false:

```
case 'x':
    option = 0;
    break;
```

> ```
> default: cout << "Invalid option entered.\n";
> ```

Consistency:

```
default:
    cout << "Invalid option entered.\n";
```

> ```
> bool analyzeData(int patientNum, double *avgHalfLife, int *numMeasurements) {
>     double C0, Ct, t, t1 / 2;
>     double sumHalfLifes = 0;
>
>     int patient;
>     ifstream fin;
>     fin.open("Patient_Data.txt");
>
>     if(fin) {
>         while(fin >> patient >> C0 >> Ct >> t) {
>             if(patient == patientNum) {
>                 bool analyzeData = true;
>                 t½ = halfLife(C0, Ct, t);
>
>                 *numMeasurements++;
>                 sumHalfLifes = sumHalfLifes + t½;
>                 *avgHalfLife = sumHalfLifes / *numMeasurements;
>             }
>         }
>     } else
>         cout << "Error opening file.";
>
>     fin.close();
>     return analyzeData;
> }
> ```

Do not declare variables with the comma operator. It makes code harder to read and follow.
Always initialize variables.
Be consistent in your declarations.

```
 bool analyzeData(int patientNum, double& avgHalfLife, int& numMeasurements) {
     double C0 = 0.0;
     double Ct = 0.0;
     double t = 0.0;
     double t_half = 0.0;
     double sumHalfLifes = 0.0;
```

> ```
> bool analyzeData = true;
> ```

You've named a variable the same as the function name. Don't do this.

```
bool is_data_analyzed = true;
```

> ```
> t½ = halfLife(C0, Ct, t);
>
> //...
> sumHalfLifes = sumHalfLifes + t½;
> ```

Unicode in variable names although allowed in some contexts is not safe, rename the variable to `t_half` or similar.

> ```
>     return analyzeData;
> ```

This does not do what you think it does! You declared `analyzeData` in an inner scope block and is therefore not visible outside of it. Because it does not exist outside that block and you named it the same as the function, you are actually returning the address to the function! Since a function's address is never zero it will always return true!

> ```
>    double k, t1 / 2;
> ```

This is just...wrong.

```
double k = 0.0;
double t_half = 0.0;
```

> ```
>    k = -log(Ct / C0) / t;
>    t½ = log(2) / k;
> ```

Is it your intention to use the natural logarithm? `std::log` is the equivalent to the mathematical "log base e" or "ln". If you want the mathematical "log base 2" or "log base 10", use `log2(...)` or `log10(...)` respectively.

> ```
> bool highest2halfLifes(double avgHalfLife, int *patient1, double *halflife1, int *patient2, double *halflife2) {
>    double highest = avgHalfLife;
>
>    if(avgHalfLife > highest)
>        highest = avgHalfLife;
>
>    return highest2halfLifes;
> ```
>
> }

This function doesn't do anything. You've initialized `highest` to `avgHalfLife` and are then checking if it is higher than `highest`. This is a contradiction. In addition you are again returning the address of the function!